# How to set width and height in dp programmatically?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I need to set width and height programmatically at `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.`

I have this formula of convertation `dp` to `px` :

```
public static int dpToPx(double dp)
{
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics;
    return (int)Math.Round(dp * (displayMetrics.Xdpi, (int)DisplayMetricsDensity.Default));
}
```

Think it's correct, but due to the fact that it returns `int` result (not `double`), sizes displays incorrectly.
It can return `double`, but `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` requires `int` type.

So, how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I believe you should cast to int only after you rounded the number the way you wanted - it could avoids truncating it.

Comment: The same result

Comment: I checked how this formula counts. And, probably, it counts wrong. Because after it -  62dp it's 217px.